# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I am getting error message `Invalid hook call`. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. I need to understand why I can't use React Hooks in the project. This is my package.json file.

```
"@types/react": "16.8.6",
 "@types/react-dom": "16.8.2",
 "react": "16.8.4",
 "react-dom": "16.8.3"
```

Following is snapshot of errors.

[image: Here is the error message]

Following is example component used in this project.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export default function ExampleComponent() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>You clicked {count} times</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is my index.tsx

```
const handleInitCompleted = (initializedServices: UuiContexts) => {
  Object.assign(svc, initializedServices);
};

const UuiEnhancedApp = withRouter(({ history }) => (
  <ContextProvider
    apiDefinition={getApi}
    loadAppContext={api => api.loadAppContext()} // tslint:disable-line
    onInitCompleted={handleInitCompleted}
    history={history}
  >
    <ExampleComponent />
    <Snackbar />
    <Modals />
  </ContextProvider>
));

const RoutedApp = () => (
  <Router>
    <UuiEnhancedApp />
  </Router>
);

const ReduxApp = () => (
  <Root>
    <RoutedApp />
  </Root>
);

ReactDOM.render(<ReduxApp />, document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement);
serviceWorker.register();
```

This is my Root.tsx file

```
interface IRootChildren {
  children: JSX.Element;
}

const middlewares = [reduxThunk, multiClientMiddleware(clients, config)];
const store = createStore(reducers, composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(...middlewares)));

export default ({ children }: IRootChildren) => {
  return (
    <Provider store={ store }>
      { children }
    </Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this,

```
npm install react@next react-dom@next
```

And ContextProvider is an HOC (Higher Order Component),
You're passing the Example Compoennt to it .
Hooks give Error inside HOC's

Comment: Thank you Zunaib Imtiaz, error disappeared after installing, but in package.json React versions become "react": "^0.0.0-b53ea6ca0" and "react-dom": "^0.0.0-b53ea6ca0". What does it mean?

Comment: thats no problem, glad to help. Select answer if you please too.

Comment: and that means that react and react-dom have the latest possible versions, latest releases.

Comment: One more question, I tried "react": "^16.12.0" and "react-dom": "^16.12.0", and it didn't work. The error appeared again. I have no idea why error disappeares with react next and appears again even with the latest version of react ^16.12.0.

Comment: You should read react documentation regarding the latest release, you'll understand better.